Responsive text truncate (ellipsis) by word in React
I'm having problem with truncating a sentence by words. Normally, I'd use  text-overflow: ellipsis; for this, but it'll cut the word in the middle.
Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lines-ellipsis but it does not work well in Vietnamese. How can I do this?
Expected Result to be a truncated sentence that fill 80% of the remaining part of a div element.


It's not worth doing something like this, but you can check this answer for suggestions if you insist

Yeah, but it's a requirement from the client.
